# How is the space complexity of below algorithm come out to be O(log n)

Tags: space-complexity

```
int[] findMinMax(int A[], int start, int end)
{
int max;
int min;
if ( start == end )
{
    max = A[start]
    min = A[start]
}
else if ( start + 1 == end )
{
    if ( A[start] < A[end] )
    {
        max = A[end]
        min = A[start]
    }
    else
    {
        max = A[start]
        min = A[end]
    }
}
else
{
    int mid = start + (end - start)/2
    int left[] = findMinMax(A, start, mid)
    int right[] = findMinMax(A, mid+1, end)
    if ( left[0] > right[0] )
        max = left[0]
    else
        max = right[0]
    if ( left[1] < right[1] )
        min = left[1]
    else
        min = right[1]
}
// By convention, we assume ans[0] as max and ans[1] as min
int ans[2] = {max, min}
 return ans
 }
```

On analysing the time complexity comes out to be O(n) using the master theorem for recursion. On looking through the pseudocode it's much clear that Divide & Conquer Algorithmic Paradigm is used. I'm facing difficulty with the space complexity part. Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays `left` and `right` get populated by the recursive calls to your function. Since the input to these calls keeps getting halved in size with each call, you will only need log n number of calls before you get to the base case where you do not need to populate them at all. The bound on auxiliary space used is therefore O(log n).